# masses and confinement

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement

I sometimes read something like "..(..) masses are below/above the confinement scale(..)". I just ask plain: What does this mean in the way: How can masses be connected to the confinement scale and what is confinement scale?

I hope it's understandable..? Maybe it's the same as in [example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.08082.pdf)? There they write

```
(...) his new framework predicts the form of the
quark-confinement potential underlying hadron spectroscopy and dynamics, and it gives
a remarkable connection between the perturbative QCD scale Λ and hadron masses (...)
```

Hence, the article [QCD scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant#QCD_scale) describes

```
In quantum chromodynamics (QCD), the quantity Λ is called the QCD scale. (...)
This value is to be used at a scale above the bottom quark mass of about 5 GeV.
```

I still can't make head or tail out of it (in general). What's the connection between mass, confinement and/or the qcd scale/scaling parameter?

Answer (score 1):

> How can masses be connected to the confinement scale and what is confinement scale?

In the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, all matter is composed from the elementary particles and the interactions between them. For hadronic matter, i.e. proton, neutrons, mesons , which we detect in the lab and measure, the model is that they are composed of quarks confined to a region in space corresponding to the measured dimensions of protons, neutrons, mesons.

[In this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html) a clear exposition of the quark model is given.

> How can one be so confident of the quark model when no one has ever seen an isolated quark? There are good reasons for the lack of direct observation. Apparently the color force does not drop off with distance like the other observed forces. It is postutated that it may actually increase with distance at the rate of about 1 GeV per fermi. A free quark is not observed because by the time the separation is on an observable scale, the energy is far above the pair production energy for quark-antiquark pairs.

Confinement, and confinement scale are relative to this observation, bounded by measurements.

There are models developed for this, for example the [bag model.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qbag.html)

Of course the mass of the bag will depend on the parameters controlling the interactions of quarks within the bag. See for example an illustration of the [contents of a proton:](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/), due to the interactions between the valence quarks.

[image: proton]

The QCD lattice model is able to calculate [masses for  hadrons](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4789), still a [research topic,](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0126) .

> What's the connection between mass, confinement and/or the qcd scale/scaling parameter?

I think if you read the linksprovided above , you will get a framework of how confinement is described in present day models.

Comment: Thank you! For a general understanding, maybe not really connected directly: Is there any lack of how is mass produced in general? Does the higgs mechanism describe it in total and we just have to study it? Or are there still some information missing?